# How to wrap #available in this custom .if extension on a SwiftUI View?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, viewbuilder, swiftui-view

I'm using this `.if` extension which works great and should be added to SwiftUI, however it won't work in this case to check `#available` because `#available may only be used as condition of an 'if', 'guard' or 'while' statement` How can I make it work with this `.if`, anyway?

```
    //Does not compile for #available may only be used as condition of an 'if', 'guard' or 'while' statement
   ForEach...
   .if(#available(iOS 15.0, *)) { $0.refreshable {
                        
                    } }

extension View {
  @ViewBuilder
  func `if`<Transform: View>(
    _ condition: Bool,
    transform: (Self) -> Transform
  ) -> some View {
    if condition {
      transform(self)
    } else {
      self
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an extension to `View` that is a `@ViewBuilder` modifier that accepts conditionals.

```
extension View {
    @ViewBuilder
    func modify(@ViewBuilder _ transform: (Self) -> (some View)?) -> some View {
        if let view = transform(self) {
            view
        } else {
            self
        }
    }
}
```

Example:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Text("Hello")
            /* More list items... */
        }
        .modify {
             if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {
                 $0.refreshable {
                     //
                 }
             }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I would typically just do `.if(true)` and then check availability inside the closure. Unfortunately, we can't check for availability in the `if` modifier.

Example:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Text("Hello")
            /* More list items... */
        }
        .if(true) {
            if #available(iOS 15, *) {
                $0.refreshable {
                    //
                }
            } else {
                $0
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Added `@ViewBuilder` to `transform` parameter so you can return different `View` types in the `if`:

```
extension View {
    @ViewBuilder func `if`<Transform: View>(_ condition: Bool, @ViewBuilder transform: (Self) -> Transform) -> some View {
        if condition {
            transform(self)
        } else {
            self
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks can you elaborate on how you would use this, for example to add .refreshable as I am trying to do to a list?

Comment: @GarySabo See the example at the top of my answer.

Comment: oh I see, you are using `.if(true)` as kind of a hack to be able to nest the if available check inside a view's body...very clever! 